# DisplayPort monitor gets disabled during boot

Tags: fedora, nvidia, monitors, amd-graphics, displayport

I have a Laptop with embedded AMD GPU and discrete NVIDIA GPU. My OS is Fedora 37.
The Laptop has a HDMI and one mini DP output. HDMI works without problems. Now I wanted to use the DP connection and bought a mini DP to HDMI adapter (as my monitors only support HDMI).

My problem is the following: the monitor will not get detected by the system after connect. When I boot with connected DP the monitor gets enabled and mirrors the boot-output for sometime and then gets disabled before SDDM starts. Sometimes it gets disabled even before SDDM, sometimes it stays enabled but is just black and sometimes it won't get enabled at all during boot.
When it gets enabled during boot (and then disabled) `xrandr --listmonitors` lists the monitor but says its disabled.

`uname -a`:
`Linux **** 6.0.14-300.fc37.x86_64 #1 SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon Dec 19 17:44:54 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

What I tried so far:

- reboot several times to test if symptoms are consistent
- tested with an other adapter which works on an other PC
- uninstalled / blacklisted NVIDIA drivers (nouveau will get loaded even if blacklisted)
- tested with Live Systems:

  - Ubuntu: monitor gets enabled and shows up in settings but image is complete garbage (except for the cursor)
  - Windows (via Hiren's Boot CD): monitor not gets detected

So my question is: can someone tell me where I should start troubleshooting this (logs, setting, etc.)?

Comment: For NVIDIA GPU related questions please ask here: https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/c/gpu-graphics/linux/148

Comment: Currently I do not know if this is related to the NVIDIA GPU or if the port is handled by the AMD GPU.
@ArtemS.Tashkinov Can you tell me, how to find this out?